# Create equidistant data frame with time ranged data with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a .cvs file in which data is stored for data ranges - from and to date columns. However, I would like to create a daily data frame with Python out of it.
The time can be ignored, as a gasday always starts at 6am and ends at 6am.

My idea was to have in the end a data frame index with a date (like from March 1st, 2019, ranging to December 31st, 2019 on a daily granularity.

I would create columns with the unique values of the identifier and as values place the respective values or nan in.

The latter one, I can easily do with pd.pivot_table, but still my problem with the time range exists...

Any ideas of how to cope with that?

time-ranged data frame

[image: time-ranged data frame]

It should look like this, just with rows in a daily granularity, considering the to column as well. Maybe with range?

[output should look similar to this, just with a different period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ZzH.png)

Comment: Can you provide your sample data in a code block?

Comment: Can you provide and example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas and groupby the column you want:

```
df=pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv")

groups=df.groupby("periodFrom")
group.get_group("2019-03-09 06:00")
```

Comment: Hey Bendig, thanks for your answer, but I think this is not what I was looking for. I adjusted my post, maybe it is clearer now.